# How to access several dymanically created Combobox at form load?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

I'm creating comboboxes on form load, but the thing is once I have added a new cb I can't access (set value, edit properties, etc) of the prior ones.

See Below Example:

```
Sub Start_stackoverflow()

    Dim strings() As String = {"Green", "Purple", "Red"}

    Dim x as integer
    For x = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
        NewDropDown(x,50,100,strings(x),strings(x))
    Next x

End Sub

Private Sub NewDropDown(ByVal Number As Integer, ByVal PosX As Integer, ByVal PosY As Integer, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Text As String)
            cbComboBox = New ComboBox
            cbComboBox.Location = New Point(150, PosY - 4%)
            cbComboBox.Name = Number
            cbComboBox.ForeColor = Color.White
            cbComboBox.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
            cbComboBox.Text = Name
            cbComboBox.AutoSize = True
            Me.Controls.Add(cbComboBox)
End Sub
```

So this is what happens, I can create the comboboxes just fine, add the values but if I wanted to edit the combobox Green for example (since it was first) I cant.
Even If I try this:

```
Sub Test()
    UpdateComboBoxCurrentlySelected(Green, MyValueIwantSelected)
End Sub

Sub UpdateComboBoxCurrentlySelected(ByVal SetGrpName As ComboBox, ByVal CurrentItem As String)
        SetGrpName.Text = (CurrentItem)
        SetGrpName.SelectedText = (CurrentItem)
        SetGrpName.SelectedItem = (CurrentItem)
        SetGrpName.SelectedIndex = (CurrentItem)
        SetGrpName.SelectedValue = (CurrentItem)
End Sub
```

Can anyone shed some light on this, that way I will know how to do it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to hold a reference to the object you want to edit:

```
'  At form level
Private dropdowns As Dictionary(Of String, Combobox) = New Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox)

'  Populate from Sub Start_stackoverflow()
Dim dropdown As ComboBox = Nothing
' ...
dropdown = NewDropDown(x,50,100,strings(x),strings(x))
dropdowns.Add(dropdown.Name, dropdown)

' change UpdateComboBoxCurrentlySelected signature to
Sub UpdateComboBoxCurrentlySelected(ByVal SetGrpName As String, ByVal CurrentItem As String)
' get the dropdown by name
Dim dropdown as ComboBox = dropdowns(SetGrpName)
' ...
```

Or you can iterate over all the controls in the form looking for the one with the name you asked for.

```
Dim foundControl As ComboBox = Nothing
For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
  If control.GetType Is GetType(ComboBox) AndAlso (control.Name = SetGrpName) Then
    foundControl = control
  End If
Next

If Not Nothing Is foundControl Then
  '  Do something with your control.
End If
```

Comment: Dan-o, thanks I'm trying to use the code you posted but its VS complaining about **control.type** `('type' is not a member of 'system.windows.forms.control')`

Comment: Then its the `GetType` method.  Didn't have VS open when I wrote it.